# Asp.net core web api slow in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
projects: .net core 2.0
server: windows server 2012 r2, IIS 8.5
```

.net core web API is slow on each request, Similar issue :
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/87

But it is fast when running visual studio debug mode.

---

Update：
it looks like a bug on IIS 8.5 with .net core, but there is no production version of IIS 10.
So I deploy my .net core to Ubuntu 16.04, and it run well.

Comment: Can you post your WebHost initialization?